# wp_remote_post To external API multiple values with the same key

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, api, wp-remote-post

I am trying to create a WP plugin that calls an external API using HTTP POST. I am using `wp_remote_post` and my arguments look like this:

```php
$body = array(
    'CustomerID' => '10',
    'Items' => ['5', '7'],
);
```

What I want to end up with is this as my POST data:

```
CustomerID=10&Items=5&Items=7
```

But this does not seems to work as expected... Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Also, how can I log the final request parameters, in the same form the external API will get them?

Comment: Method is set to `GET`? Like `wp_remote_post('<API_URI>', array('method' => 'GET', 'timeout' => 15, 'redirection' => 5, 'httpversion' => '1.0', 'blocking' => true, 'headers' => array(), 'body' => array('CustomerID' => urlencode(10), 'Items' => array(5, 7)), 'cookies' => array()));`

Comment: No, it's set on POST. Sorry I as not very clear with that. I have updated my question.

Comment: What you can do is create the url in that way by using concatenation. Something like `'<API_URI>?CustomerID='.$body['CustomerID'].'&Items='.$body['Items'][0].'&Items='..$body['Items'][1]` Otherwise you can change the method to get as shown in the example in my previous comment.

Comment: I was hoping to use POST, but GET is also an option. However a simple GET will not get me the final URL I want. I will probably use a for loop to build the final URL...

Comment: Not sure why you need that particular url structure but yes, iterating through the variables will provide you that structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a requirement of the external API I am trying to use... Not a very well designed API structure...

Comment: Even if the api accepts that structure, I am pretty sure that using **get** with `wp_remote_post` should work as I use this code with different parameters on an api that accepts get request.